# What is a `\document class clv2`. Why it has so many compatibility issues

Tags: document-classes

I am using Texmaker to write an paper in  `\document class clv2`. I have already written the same paper in `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` but conversion in `\document class clv2` is so difficult. Why it has so many compatibility issues? If anyone has used this document class in past, please guide me with algorithms, specially nested loops. I want my algorithm to look something like this.[image]

Comment: It would help to know where you found this 'strange' class `clv2.cls`

Comment: @Christian, this is the document class of the template of one of the best journals by MIT Press.

Comment: And where can we find this template of one of the best journals by MIT Press?

Comment: Asking several times the same question is a good method for not receiving answers. Each of your questions on this topic lack a fundamental thing: a minimal example of code to play with.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: My working model <br/>     \documentclass[fullname]{clv2}  <br/>    \begin{document}  <br/>     \begin{algorithm}    <br/>    \SetAlgoLined
\BlankLine
\KwData{Input}
\KwResult{PMI}
\BlankLine
\Begin
{
\textbf{Perform:}\\  
Token\\     
\For {each Token}
{
blah  \\
\If{C }
{
Write
}
}
\For {each}
{
U= F\\
B “+” F
}
\For {each}
{
U =1\\ B =1\\
\For {each}
{
\If {i = j}                                             {
U+=1
}
\If {i = j}                                             {
B+=1
}
}
}
\For {each}
{
$
P = log
\frac
{B}%
{(U*U[i+1])} 
$\
}
}  
\caption{PMI}   \end{algorithm}    \end{document}